# TF293000: The data warehouse has detected data conflicts for the following work item fields

Tags: reporting-services, tfs, ssrs-2012, tfs-workitem

Hi I'm looking for help with the following issue:

In TFS on our SSRS report server whenever I run any of the out the box Sprint Burndown reports the report seems to run successfully but I get the following error in the bottom right hand corner:

[image: TF293000]

Through some research I found that the issue was due to the field definitions in that particular Collection not matching the other collections that we have in TFS. Simple...

In order to determine which field definition in the collection was the issue I used the `witadmin` command `listfields` for all of my collections:

`witadmin listfields /collection:Collection /n:Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ReviewedBy`

This led me to find that the `Synchronizes Identity Name Changes` definition in the collection mentioned in the TF293000 error was set to a value of `true`, while it is `false` in all of my other collections. Issue Found! Should be easy from here...wrong.

The following command should solve my problem:

`witadmin changefield /collection:Collection /n:Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ReviewedBy /syncnamechanges:false`

*of course with the proper collection url subbed in for the word Collection

However when run and after I confirm that I want to make the change I get the following error:

> TF401327: The operation is not supported. The feature is obselete.

I look the error up and it takes me to this page [TFS Known Issue](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3077455/team-foundation-server-2015-known-issues) which tells me it's a known issue but was resolved in update 1 ... we have update 3.

I then attempted to simply edit the WIT .xml file and update the attribute for that WIT on that collection with `false`, but when I import the change to the server it tells me it has imported successfully however when I export it I see that the file has not changed.

I have also tried copying the the .xml file from the same WIT in another collection and uploading that to the offending collection and that will not work. I've never had an issue with uploading a WIT as we've made several changes to our TFS workflow before. I'm pretty stuck at this point and just wondering if anyone else has experienced this issue before, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the error info, seems there is a conflict in the TFS Data warehouse and this because 2 fields in different collection has different attributes in the data warehouse as it’s only one data warehouse. To avoid schema conflicts when you export and process data to the data warehouse databases, you must assign the same values to these attributes across all collections:

- Field type (the value for this field cannot be changed for an
  existing field).
- Reporting type.
- Reporting name.

What you have done is the correct operation, change/update  the attribute for the field in one project collection to match the assignments that are made in other project collections.

You could try to narrow the issue, if this issue only happened on that specific field in the team project collection. All other work item filed working correctly? Also give a try with other collections, such as change the syncnamechanges=true, then set it back to syncnamechanges=false, to see if any issue occurs.

Run the command line on TFS sever machine instead of your develop machine. [Clear TFS cahce](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vsalm/2013/12/17/how-to-clear-the-tfs-cache-on-client-machines/). And if the filed is not use for reporting about those project collections, you could also try to mark it as non-reportable. More details please refer below links:

- [Resolve data warehouse schema conflicts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/report/admin/resolve-schema-conflicts?toc=/vsts/report/sql-reports/toc.json#resolve-schema-conflicts)
- [Change a reportable attribute for a work item field](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/customize/reference/add-or-modify-work-item-fields-to-support-reporting#change-a-reportable-attribute-for-a-work-item-field)

Comment: I went ahead and changed all the other project collection's synchnamechanges value to "true" and after a few minutes the error disappears. Also the ReviewedBy column in the DB now has records to reflect the change. I guess MS no longer supports synchnamechanges=false.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'm having the exact issue with the "Code Review Response" WIT and the ReviewedBy field. The above steps are generally good advice (except we don't install Visual Studio on the app tier machine, so running the command line on the TFS server machine doesn't make sense for us.)